# The correct way to think in french - How to build sentences?

Tags: grammaire

In English, and all the rest of the Germanic languages, we say:

```
I called them for to tell them
```

But in romance languages, we can say:

```
Je leur télephone pour dire leur
```

Translated word by word, it will be come

```
I them phone for tell them
```

Is this a correct way to "thinking in french".
Anoter example.

If I have broken my leg, then I say.

```
I have hurt my leg
```

The structure for the other Germanic languages are the same.

But in romance languages, it's:

```
Je me suis cassé ma jambe
```

Translated word by word:

```
I myself is broken my leg
```

Is this the correct way of thinking in french? For example, If I want to say "I'm going to your house" in french, then I would say

```
I your is walking to house yours?
```

Or can it be:

```
I your is walking to your house?
```

Or:

```
I is your walking to your house?
```

So what's the correct way to use "I/You/We" followed by another noun as a person?

Comment: No expertise other than with the French language may be required to answer. You can take a look at word order [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_grammar#Word_order). You cannot speak French by translating on the fly a pattern made out of English language labels representing French language word order so I don't understand what you expect to gain here? How is that supposed to provide you or anywone with any insight into the language or to help you improve phrasing and wording in French? I can't even guess what French sentence you see in _I your is walking to house yours_.

Comment: In German, isn't the word order *I have my leg hurt*? Or maybe *I have of me the leg hurt?* The word order of German and English differs quite a bit. I think your premise is incorrect.

Comment: @AmandeAdorable They all was just examples if I translate word by word. The last sentences was just examples for questions about how french sentences are built up. "I he went to his house - Je lui allé chez lui".

Comment: You should first make sure your "French" sentences are correct which is far from being the case.  *Je leur télephone pour dire leur* is broken, *Je me suis cassé ma jambe* is questionable and I have no idea about what sentence you expect behind *I your is walking to house yours*.

Comment: and please, capitalize language names in English.

Comment: _Je suis allé chez lui_. So if your question is can I generate any sentence simply by putting a pronoun in front of a verb, well it's not as simple as that clearly. You have to look at the transitivity for each verb, figure out what type of complement they call for, then use the correct pronoun depending on function and meaning as a single verb might be used with a direct or indirect complement, both or none at all. Then you have the typical word order I linked which shows you what may happen when there are more than one complement, then there are set phrases, register etc. This is a language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi Daniel :) as a French instructor, I really encourage you to NOT use a translation process when you're learning or speaking French; try to work within the language... The structure in French is SVC: Sujet + Verbe + Complément. Once you have that in your *French box*, you can then build the sentences you want/need.

A little correction: you would say *Je me suis cassé la jambe.* You already talk about yourself with the reflexive verb (*verbe pronominal)* so you don't need to add the *possessif*. ;-)

What did you mean in your last question?

Comment: Thank you. I mean if I want to tell another e.g person something, I say "I + him" e.g. "Je lui...". Is it always like this? "I told  him" becaome "Je lui dire" and not "Je dire lui"?

Comment: @DanielMårtensson _Je lui ai dit_. This is _dire quelque chose à quelqu'un_, the preposition _à_ is used to introduce the indirect object in this case, which can be replaced with _lui_ before the main verb here.